# How to write a list of dataframes into multiple sheets of ExcelLocalDataSet?

Tags: kedro

The input is a list of dataframes. How can I save it into an ExcelLocalDataSet where each dataframe is a separate sheet?

Comment: I suppose if saving into multiple sheets is not supported, so is the case with reading multiple sheet.

Answer (score 1):

Currently the [`ExcelLocalDataset`](https://kedro.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/kedro/io/excel_local.html#ExcelLocalDataSet) implementation is currently geared towards writing one sheet and this presents two possible actions for you:

1. The [`ExcelLocalDataset`](https://kedro.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/kedro/io/excel_local.html#ExcelLocalDataSet) uses `XlsxWriter`. You could extend or transform [`ExcelLocalDataset`](https://kedro.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/kedro/io/excel_local.html#ExcelLocalDataSet) to iterate over a list of DataFrames and write the sheets, getting inspiration from the example below:

```
# Create some Pandas dataframes from some data.
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Data': [11, 12, 13, 14]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Data': [21, 22, 23, 24]})
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'Data': [31, 32, 33, 34]})

# Create a Pandas Excel writer using XlsxWriter as the engine.
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('pandas_multiple.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

# Write each dataframe to a different worksheet.
df1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
df2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet2')
df3.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet3')

# Close the Pandas Excel writer and output the Excel file.
writer.save()
```

*Sourced from [**here**](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_pandas_multiple.html)*

2. If your use case uses data that's the same but just split across the different sheets that then you may want to check out using the natively supported `PartitionedDataSet` in combination with the `ExcelLocalDataSet`. The [`PartitionedDataSet`](https://kedro.readthedocs.io/en/stable/04_user_guide/08_advanced_io.html#partitioned-dataset) can recursively load all or specific files from a given location.